# How to revert Firefox

Tags: firefox, versions

A recent update to Firefox has made my profiles unusable, and they were already indecipherable.  So I want to revert to a previous version and create readable backups of my bookmarks, and take note of active Addons.

The bookmarks list is quite long, and is essential to my workflow and failing memory.

So: is there a way to revert?  What's the latest version before the format change?

I'm on Xubuntu 20.04.5 with .deb Firefox.  I have older installs in other directories, but they are VERY old.
I have backups, but they are also quite old at this point -- at least a year.

Comment: Do you have backups? Older versions had profile with all your info in /home in hidden folder .mozilla. Snaps may have copued into snap. `ll .mozilla/firefox` If you have old profile, you can to new Firefox but not as a snap. You also have to reset priorities as shown or it will reinstall the Firefox snap.
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the question partly got answered.  In looking at ~/.mozilla I saw profiles that had been created in my thrashing around, so I tried invoking them, and lo-and-behold I got a Firefox to start up.  Moreover, although they were disorganized, I found a huge chunk of the missing bookmarks were available because I had imported bookmarks from Chrome (which had previously imported from Firefox).

So the rest should be a fairly straight-forward cleanup process.  If I'm missing some bookmarks, I can probably create them.  I just dreaded having to create ALL of them.